# Cross-platform pager with xamarin.form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Android it has a class named ViewPager to support "Gestural navigation allows the user to swipe left and right to step through pages of data." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/view-pager/)

But my task is write cross-platform codes for both Android & iOS (without rewrite new code for this gesture). With Xamarin.Form does any library support this ? I have read about Xamarin.Form carousel, but it seem used for slideshow, not appropriate for news list.

Answer (score 0):

I think `TabbedPage` is more suitable for you. tabbedPage support the Gestural navigation allows the user to swipe left and right to step through pages of data, just set the different pages of data in different tabs.

Here is running GIF.

[image]

You can add this Tabbedpage like following code.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageDemo;assembly=TabbedPageDemo"
        x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.TabbedPageDemoPage">
       <TabbedPage.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary>
           <local:NonNullToBooleanConverter x:Key="booleanConverter" />
          </ResourceDictionary>
       </TabbedPage.Resources>
        <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
           <ContentPage Title="{Binding Name}" Icon="monkeyicon.png">
             <StackLayout Padding="5, 25">
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
              Font="Bold,Large"
              HorizontalOptions="Center" />
              <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}"
                WidthRequest="200" 
                HeightRequest="200" />
      <StackLayout Padding="50, 10">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="Family:"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Family}"
                 Font="Bold,Medium" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     IsVisible="{Binding Subfamily,
                        Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}">
          <Label Text="Subfamily:"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Subfamily}"
                 Font="Bold,Medium" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     IsVisible="{Binding Tribe,
                        Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}">
          <Label Text="Tribe:"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Tribe}"
                 Font="Bold,Medium" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="Genus:"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Genus}"
                 Font="Bold,Medium" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage>
   </DataTemplate>
  </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

You can add different `ItemTemplate` in the Tabbedpage.
Here is a related link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

**Update: you can add the listview in the tabbpage like following GIF.**

[image]

Comment: This is not support vertical swipe. It's not suitable for news  flipped-pages

Comment: But you can add the listview in everyPages, `Listview` support the vertical swipe, or use scrollview to show other datas.

Comment: @GiangNguyễn I update my answer, you can refer to it.

Comment: No. This is exactly what i'm talking about: https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager/raw/master/art/zoom_out.gif

Comment: This Switching result is add the animation when transfer pages like this Custom page transitions(look like the `Slide from top`):https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions